# One prop comes defined, other one is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Can someone explain and help me to understand why one prop that I pass is fine, but other one comes undefined?

Comments prop is fine, it renders the comment with its data. Something prop comes undefined

Main.tsx

```
<Comment comments={comment} something={'test'}/>
```

Comment.tsx

```
interface CommentProps {
  comments: {
    id: string,
    author: {
      name: string,
      picture: string
    },
    text: string,
    timestamp: number
  },
  something?: string
}

import { useEffect } from "react"

const Comment = (props: CommentProps) => {

  const { id, author, text, timestamp } = props.comments

  const testing = props.something
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(testing)
  }, [testing])
```

and in the end `testing` comes as `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because of the empty dependencies array:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(testing)
  }, [])
```

Put `props` there.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(testing)
  }, [props])
```

Comment: Although I forgot to add it, same thing happens. It's undefined again.